# Where is the special_price/special_to_date/special_from_date held at?

Tags: collection, sql, resource-model, zend-framework

I have a query for the catalog/product model and that has an associated properties of special price field, I can access them normally by using the model, however when using `getSelect()` it will only get me the table `catalog_product_entity`, which does not contain what I need.

Here is what I am using:

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->getSelect()
        ->where(
            " ( special_from_date > '$todayDate' OR  special_to_date < '$todayDate' )
             OR  ( special_from_date IS NULL AND special_to_date IS NULL ) ");
        ->query();
```

As you might expect this will return the column not found error.

Oh and if you are wondering, why don't I just use filters? The issue is that Its very ugly to create a filter with the combination `(V OR V) OR (V AND V)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$todayStartOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('00:00:00')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

$todayEndOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('23:59:59')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('special_price', 'special_to_date', 'special_from_date'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
         'special_from_date', 
          array(
              'or'=> array(
                  0 => array(
                      'date' => true, 
                      'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate
                  ),
                  1 => array(
                      'is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')
                  )
               )
          ), 
          'left'
     )
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        'special_to_date', 
        array(
            'or'=> array(
                0 => array(
                    'date' => true, 
                    'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate
                ),
                1 => array(
                     'is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')
                )
            )
        ), 
        'left'
    )
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
         array(
              array(
                   'attribute' => 'special_from_date', 
                   'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')
              ),
              array(
                   'attribute' => 'special_to_date', 
                   'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')
              )
         )
    );
```

This should get you the list of products that have a valid special price today. I assume that's what you want.

Comment: Yes, I guess I should have actually posted that I already have a solution like that, however as you can see that is an insane amount of code for a simple query. Although, I can see the 'or', which I did not know existed, I'll try it with that(I'll be trying the and :)) Thanks.

Comment: I agree...the query is not the most beautiful one, but this way is safer. This way your timezone is taken into consideration also. If you did this directly on the db fields you might get inconsistent results due to timezone settings.

Comment: Doesn't the models use UTC time, which is then localized? And what does the "left" do?

Comment: I have no idea what 'left' does. I think is something related to the join is done with the values table. As for UTC time I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: All time's that are stored into the database are converted from the locale to the UTC/GMT time. I need to confirm though. You can see it littered all over the code though, date_default_timezone_set('UTC'). Then it stores.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I derivated from @Marius 's answer

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            array(
                array(
                    'attribute' =>'special_from_date',
                    'date' => true,
                    'gt' => $todayDate
                    ),
                array(
                    'attribute' =>'special_to_date',
                    'date' => true,
                    'lt' => $todayDate
                    ),
                'or' => array(
                        'attribute' =>'special_from_date',
                        'date' => true,
                        'null' => true,
                        'and' => array(
                        'attribute' =>'special_to_date',
                        'date' => true,
                        'null' => true
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
```

And it works !